# Como extraigo 2 palabras que pueden variar de una cadena con regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, inteligencia-artificial

Estaba intentado hacer un bot de toma de deciciones

```py
import random

i = False

positive_words = []
negative_words = []

#En los puntos .txt deben estar cada palabra y un Entes, por eso agregamos el /n al input, y en la ultima palabra del .txt poner un Enter tambien
pos_path = 'C:/Users/PC0/Desktop/P/Python/Projects/decision_algorithm/positive.txt'
neg_path = 'C:/Users/PC0/Desktop/P/Python/Projects/decision_algorithm/negative.txt'

with open(pos_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
    #positive_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
    positive_words.extend(textfile.readlines())
print(positive_words)

with open(neg_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
    #negative_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
    negative_words.extend(textfile.readlines())
print(negative_words)


wordA = str(input()+'\n')
wordB = str(input()+'\n')


if wordA in positive_words and wordB in positive_words:
    answer_num = random.randint(1, 2) #numero inicial y final del rango del cual queremos generar numeros

    if answer_num == 1:
        print("No estoy seguro, ya que ambas son buenas opciones")
    elif answer_num == 2:
        print("Creo que elijo, ", str(random.choice([wordA, wordB])))


elif wordA in positive_words and wordB in negative_words:
    print("Creo que elijo", wordA)

elif wordA in negative_words and wordB in positive_words:
    print("Creo que elijo", wordB)

elif wordA in negative_words and wordB in negative_words:
    answer_num = random.randint(1, 2) #numero inicial y final del rango del cual queremos generar numeros

    if answer_num == 1:
        print("No estoy seguro, ya que ambas son malas opciones")
    elif answer_num == 2:
        print("Aunque ambas son malas opciones creo que elijo, ", str(random.choice([wordA, wordB])))


else:

    if not wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
        if wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
            print("Lo siento, pero no puedo elegir si no conozco que es la palabra " + wordA)
        elif not wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
            print("Lo siento pero no puedo elegir si no conozco ninguna de esas palabras")
            i = True

    if not wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
        if wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
            print("Lo siento, pero no puedo elegir si no conozco que es la palabra " + wordB)
        elif not wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
            if i == False:
                print("Lo siento pero no puedo elegir si no conozco ninguna de esas palabras")
            else:
                pass


i = False
```

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora, pero quiero cambiar esos inputs, por una entrada de una unica oracion con alguna de estas estructuras:

```
    "Que sugieres ((\\w+\\s*)+) o ((\\w+\\s*)+)",
    "Que eliges ((\\w+\\s*)+) o ((\\w+\\s*)+)",
    "Que eligirias ((\\w+\\s*)+) o ((\\w+\\s*)+)"
```

donde el primer ((\w+\s*)+) seria wordA y el segundo la wordB

Como hago para guardar esas 2 palabras que no sabemos cuales son dentro las respectivas variables para poner en funcionamiento el algoritmo ? Tene en cuenta que las palabras son de longitud variable, no puedo tomar palabras de un largo en especifico como referencia.

PD: dentro de los .txt hay palabras que tu debes cargar una debajo de otra, por ejemplo en positive.txt estan asi:

```
bueno
bondad
alegria
felicidad
lindo
```

y en negative.txt

```
malo
maldad
tristeza
depresion
feo
```

y obviamente se pueden agregar mas palabras para que el bot tenga mas amplitud de deciciones a tomar.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

---

Agrando quedaria asi pero sigue teniendo problemas con los espacios

```py
patron = r"(?:que sugieres|que eliges|que elegirias|te quedarias con|eligirias|selecciona|selecciona entre) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

frase = input().lower()
#print(type(frase))

m = re.search(patron, frase)
if m:
    print(m.groups())

wordA, wordB = m.groups()
wordA = wordA + "\n"
wordB = wordB + "\n"
wordA = wordA.strip()
wordB = wordB.strip()
```

Comment: No entiendo tu expresión regular. Al tener dentro `\s*` admites que WordA o WordB pueda tener dentro un número arbitrario de espacios. ¿No deberían ser WordA y WordB palabras únicas? Además, ya que `\w+\s*`  va entre paréntesis y con un `+` fuera, básicamente WordA podría ser cualquier secuencia de palabras, separadas por espacios y Word B lo mismo. En ese caso ¿cómo decides donde termina WordA? ¿Cuando aparece la conjunción "o"? ¿Puede aparecer esa conjunción también como parte de WordA?

Comment: Lo se pero lo puse para probar. El tema es que no se como capturar esas palabras y guardar cada una en las respectivas variables.
El orden de en que variable se guardarian seria el de aparicion en la cadena.
Pero no se con que cortar para determinar hasta donde es wordA y cuando empezar a tomar wordB. Podria guiarme por los espacios ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si entiendo correctamente la pregunta, pero creo que lo que necesitas es el concepto de "grupos de captura".

Cuando en una expresión regular pones algo entre paréntesis, eso no sólo sirve para agrupar "unidades" (como en tu caso las palabras seguidas de espacios), sino que además crea "grupos de captura". Esos grupos forman parte del resultado y puedes después acceder a ellos por sus índices.

Si quieres usar paréntesis con el único propósito de agrupar dentro de la expresión regular pero no quieres que se cree un grupo de captura, puedes usar `(?:)`. Por ejemplo, tus tres expresiones podrían ser una sola si usas un grupo con el operador | para admitirentre "sugieres", "eliges" o  "elegirías". Así:
`"Que (sugieres|eliges|elegirias) ..."`. Pero entonces se crearía un grupo de captura que contendría qué palabra de esas tres fue la utilizada. Si no necesitas esa información usarías `"Que (?:sugieres|eliges|elegirias) ..."` que sigue agrupando esas palabras para el operador |, pero no crea un grupo de captura en el resultado.

Con esta idea de los grupos de captura y los grupos de no-captura, yo escribiría tu expresión regular así:

```
patron = r"Que (?:sugieres|eliges|elegirias) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)"
```

Fíjate cómo he usado `(?:)` para la agrupación de las tres palabras posibles, y también para la agrupación del `\w+\s*`, de modo que esos grupos no formarían capturas en el resultado. Sin embargo he usado `()` alrededor de los grupos que sí quiero que aparezcan en el resultado, que serían básicamente los resultados que buscas y que llamabas WordA y WordB.

En python el resultado de aplicar `re.search()` es un objeto de tipo `Match`, y tiene un método llamado `groups()` que te retorna los grupos de captura hallados.

Demo de uso:

```
import re

frases  = [
           "Que sugieres pizza o burger",
           "Que elegirias pizza hut o burger king",
           "Que eliges Sinead o Connor o Enya"
]

for frase in frases:
  m = re.search(patron, frase)
  if m:
     print(m.groups())
```

Sale:

```
('pizza', 'burger')
('pizza hut', 'burger king')
('Sinead o Connor', 'Enya')
```

Como ves, `m.groups()` te devuelve una tupla con dos elementos. El `[0]` sería la primera palabra y el `[1]` la segunda. También podrías hacer:

```
wordA, wordB = m.groups()
```

**Nota**. Observa el último ejemplo. "Sinead o Connor o Enya". La "o" aparece dos veces. ¿Cómo decidir dónde acaba WordA? Podría ser "Sinead o Connor", y ser "Enya" la otra palabra. O podría ser "Sinead" la primera y "Connor o Enya" la segunda.

Por defecto las expresiones regulares son "glotonas" (*greedy*) lo que significa que van a intentar capturar el máximo posible antes de agotar el grupo. Por eso ha considerado "Sinead o Connor" como el primer grupo capturado. Casualmente era la respuesta correcta. Pero fallará si le hubiéramos puesto: "Enya o Sinead o Connor".

Puedes hacer que un grupo no sea *greedy* si añades un `?` al final, antes de cerrar el paréntesis. En ese caso el primer grupo se detendría tan pronto como encuentre una "o" que ya consideraría el delimitador.

Este caso es ambiguo y espero que no se presente entre tus frases.

## Edición

Ante preguntas adicionales del OP, que quiere permitir que al final de la cadena aparezca una interrogación y quizás espacios, plantea usar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
patron = r"(?:que sugieres|que eliges|que elegirias|te quedarias con|eligirias|selecciona|selecciona entre) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
```

El problema es que en varios casos en los que aparezcan espacios antes del interrogante final, o espacios extra entre palabras, esos espacios acabarían en los grupos de captura y no se desea eso.

Lo que proponía era dejarlo así, y luego eliminar espacios superfluos mediante el método `.strip()`.

El siguiente ejemplo muestra cómo funcionaría (ya de paso he puesto `IGNORECASE` para que no influya la diferencia mayúsculas/minúsculas):

```
for frase in frases:
  m = re.search(patron, frase, re.IGNORECASE)
  if m:
    wordA, wordB = m.groups()
    wordA = wordA.strip()
    wordB = wordB.strip()    
    print((wordA, wordB))
```

Es decir, si se produjo el match, se extraen los grupos hallados a dos variables, `wordA` y `wordB`. Después se aplica `strip()` a cada una, lo que eliminará espacios que puedan tener por delante o por detrás.

Para las frases siguientes:

```
frases  = [
           "que sugieres pizza   o burger",
           "que elegirias pizza hut o burger king  ",
           "que eliges Sinead o Connor o Enya   ?"
]
```

la salida es:

```
('pizza', 'burger')
('pizza hut', 'burger king')
('Sinead o Connor', 'Enya')
```

Comment: ```
patron = r"que (?:sugieres|eliges|elegirias) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)(?: ?|?| )"
```
Para poner la opcion de que ponga un ?, un espacio y el ?, o que no ponga nada al final, esto no me funciona, sabes porque pasa eso?

Comment: El signo `?` tiene significado especial dentro de una expresión regular. Usa `\?` cuando te refieras a ese signo literal, sin su significado especial.

Comment: Pero yo no usaría un grupo con | para expresar que al final puede haber espacios o interrogante opcionales. Para los espacios opcionales puedes poner `\s*` y el interrogante opcional sería  `\??` (ya que `?` dentro de una regex significa que el carácter anterior es opcional). Por tanto yo usaría `patron = r"Que (?:sugieres|eliges|elegirias) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"`

Comment: El del ? sin el espacio anda, pero si hay un espacio ese espacio lo mete dentro de la wordB, y lo detecta como algo distinto, creo que el \s* no me funciono ?

que sugieres bueno o malo ?
('bueno', 'malo ')
Lo siento, pero no puedo elegir si no conozco que es la palabra malo

Comment: También puedes dejar la expresión como estaba y librarte de espacios supérfluos alrededor de los grupos capturados, usando `wordA.strip()`, `wordB.strip()`. Esta solución puede ser más general, ya que también tendrías espacios al inicio o fin de `wordA` o `wordB` si el usuario mete varios espacios separando, como en `"Que eliges   bueno   o    malo"`. El `strip()` los eliminaría.

Comment: patron = r"(?:que sugieres|que eliges|que elegirias) ((?:\w+\s*)+) o ((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

frase = input().lower()
#print(type(frase))

m = re.search(patron, frase)
if m:
 print(m.groups())

wordA, wordB = m.groups()
wordA = wordA + "\n"
wordB = wordB + "\n"
wordA = wordA.strip()
wordB = wordB.strip()

Esto no me esta funcionando, porque eso strip() no me quitan por alguna razon los espacio o debo aclararlos?

Tira esto: 

que sugieres bueno  o malo
('bueno ', 'malo  ')
Lo siento pero no puedo elegir si no conozco ninguna de esas palabras

Comment: ahi lo puse en edicion, porque en comentarios no se ve bien

Comment: No debes editar mi respuesta para ampliar tu pregunta. Para eso edita tu pregunta :-) Ya he movido tus añadidos a tu pregunta, que es donde deben estar

Comment: lo siento lo puse sin pensar, y respecto a lo del strip() lo puse al finalizar patron y luego del input de la frase a la vez, pero sigue fallando incluso si lo indico como .strip(" ")

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta para mostrar como hacer lo del strip

Comment: Tuve que cambiar en el mio que se agregan las \n luego de hacer el strip() ya que este tambien las quita, y al final quedo funcionando bien. Muchicimas gracias por la ayuda y la explicacion.